# php upload max filesize change but nothing change happens

Tags: php, jquery, nginx, jquery-file-upload

I just want to upload high resolution images, for this I'm using [jquery file uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).  I'm using Nginx.

```
upload_max_filesize =100M
post_max_size =100M
```

This php.ini file is at `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` , I have restarted it by using `sudo service php5-fpm` restart and `sudo service nginx restart`

But nothing happens
still getting the error 
and increase `client_max_body_size 100M` in nginx as well.

phpinfo still shows `upload_max_filesize = 2M`

Comment: What are you running the `phpinfo` from? CLI or via the web setup you describe? Check the information it's giving you and have a look for the loaded configuration line and make sure that the file you're changing is the one that PHP is actually using.

Comment: I am checking phpinfo from web and Loaded Configuration File it shows is `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

Comment: Next thing to check is if any other configuration files are loaded that may override your... override.

Comment: have you .htaccess file per project ??

Comment: No i don't have any .htaccess file

Answer (score -3):

You have to restart xampp to view changes

Comment: He is using nginx, it has nothing to do with xampp.